# One-To-Many relationship with UniqueKey constraint

Tags: sql-server-2008, fluent-nhibernate, has-many, unique-key

I'm new to Fluent-NHibernate. 
My problem is that a want to establish a one-to-many relationship between two entities.
A product can have multiple (unique) revisions, and a specific revision only belongs to one product.
So for example Product1 has a revision "a" and a revision "b", but can't have two revisions "a". That's what my class definitions look like:

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int ID {get; private set;}
    public IList<ProductRevision> revisions { get; set; }

}


public class ProductRevision
{
        public virtual int ID {get; private set;}
        public Product isRevisionOf { get; set; }
        public virtual string revision { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my mapping

```
public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{

    public ProductMap()
    {

        Id(x => x.ID).Column("ProductNo");
        HasMany(x => x.revisions).Cascade.All();
    }

}

public class ProductRevisionMap : ClassMap<ProductRevision>
{
    public ProductDefinitionFormationMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
        References(x => x.isRevisionOf).UniqueKey("Product_Revision").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.revision).UniqueKey("Product_Revision").Not.Nullable();

}

}
```

What I get now is redundant column "Product_Id" in the ProductRevision table. A'm I getting something wrong by defining the relation on BOTH sides with hasMany() and references(). 
Normally I wouldn't define the References(...) mapping, but I need it for the uniquekey constraint, don't I?

Thanks,
Erik

Comment: What do these two tables look like as far as the primary/foreign keys are concerned.  I'm thinking you are making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bi-directional one-to-many relation and the mapping may look something like this:

```
public ProductMap()
{
    Id(x => x.ID).Column("ProductNo");
    HasMany(x => x.revisions)
        .KeyColumn("ProductId") // the name of the FK column in ProductRevision table
        .Inverse() // bi-directional relation
        .Cascade.All();
}

public ProductRevisionMap()
{
    Id(x => x.ID);
    References(x => x.isRevisionOf)
        .Column("ProductId") // column name must match the name specified in Product HasMany
        .UniqueKey("Product_Revision")
        .Not.Nullable();
    Map(x => x.revision).UniqueKey("Product_Revision").Not.Nullable();
}
```

Inverse and KeyColumn are the missing pieces of this puzzle.

This mapping generates required constraint in database but you will still need to check this constraint in business logic as well otherwise you will get SqlException if a revision with duplicate name is inserted into revisions collection.